# How to Correctly Integrate SwiperJS into an Astro Component to Avoid Module Resolver Errors?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js, astrojs

I'm working on a project using Astro and trying to integrate SwiperJS. Everything works as expected locally, but as soon as I deploy my application to the server, issues arise. Specifically, I encounter an error when attempting to import SwiperJS through a  tag in my .astro file. The error I receive is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@swiper/swiper-bundle.min.mjs". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

Here's a snippet of my code showing how I'm trying to integrate SwiperJS:

```
<script type="module">
    import Swiper from '@swiper/swiper-bundle.min.mjs';
    // Initialize Swiper...
</script>
```

I have tried various methods to fix this error, including changing the import path to relative and absolute paths, but I still get similar error messages.

Questions:

How can I integrate SwiperJS into an Astro component without encountering module resolver errors, especially when deploying to a server?
Is there a specific way import paths should be handled in Astro to avoid such issues?
Has anyone experienced something similar and found a solution that works both locally and on the server?
I followed the guide for integrating SwiperJS into Astro, but this specific issue does not seem to be directly addressed in the documentation or common guides. Any help or advice on how to resolve this import error would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Astro docs](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/client-side-scripts/):

> Astro will not process your script tags in some situations. In particular, adding `type="module"` or any attribute other than `src` to a `<script>` tag will cause Astro to treat the tag as if it had an `is:inline` directive.

Thus you need to write the script tag without `type="module"`. And for the CSS to be bundled by Astro, you need to import it as part of the front-matter:

```
---
import 'swiper/css';
---

<div class="swiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
  import Swiper from 'swiper';
  const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {});
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I've now checked everything again and discovered that Astro doesn't bundle my code at all. Which of course means that it doesn't work. I have to find out what the problem is

Comment: I got it working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-5exmwx?file=src%2Fpages%2Findex.astro so your problem must be somewhere else...

Comment: For me the slider doesn't work in stackblitz.

The slider works in the Dev environment. Without problems. As soon as I create the build it no longer works.
When I look at the build the code is missing. when I use type="modele" I get an error in the console. Since the imports no longer work properly here. Because he can't handle the import Swiper from swiper.

I don't know what the problem is at the moment, maybe I need to optimize the build process or just import code differently

Comment: odd, the stackblitz works for me: on a desktop, you just need to drag the slides horizontally with the mouse... (it even works when I ctrl-c in the stackblitz terminal and then do `npm run build && npm run preview`). What do you mean with "When I look at the build the code is missing"?